# Executing a command and storing its output in a variable

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to write a python script that, among many things, calls an executable and stores what that executable sends to stdout in a variable. Here is what I have:

```
 1 #!/usr/bin/python
  2 import subprocess
  3 
  4 subprocess.call("./pmm", shell=True)
```

How would I get the output of pmm to be stored in a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["./pmm"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.stdout.read()
```

Comment: This may deadlock if the process produces a lot of output.  Use `p.communicate()` instead of `p.stdout.read()`. (See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout) -- scroll up a bit.)

Comment: that doesn't make much sense as the deadlock warning is on `p.wait()` (as if the output buffer fills the process will wait until it has room thus the dead lock if the reading process is waiting on it) not `p.stdout.read()` which like `p.communicate()` will fail if the output is large or unlimited in which case it would be best to read in chunks.

Comment: @Dan D: The warning is directly above the documentation of `Popen.stdout` and reads "Use `communicate()` rather than `.stdin.write`, `.stdout.read` or `.stderr.read` to avoid deadlocks [...]".

Comment: Thinking about it, this won't deadlock if the process produces a lot of output on stdout, but rather if there is a lot of output on stderr to fill up the buffer of a file descriptor that is not being read.

Comment: yes, but if you don't write to `p.stdin` and only read from `p.stdout`, there can't be a deadlock.

Comment: If you use ``p.communicate()`` in place of p.stdout.read(), you should also add the param ``stderr=subprocess.PIPE`` to the Popen call.

Answer (score 6):

In Python 2.7 (and 3.1 or above), you can use [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).  Example from the documentation:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-l", "/dev/null"])
'crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Oct 18  2007 /dev/null\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a post about this some time ago:

http://trifoliummedium.blogspot.com/2010/12/running-command-line-with-python-and.html

Use p.communicate() to get both stdout and stderr

Answer (score 0):

First you have to save a reference to the subprocess (bind it to a name ... which, in other languages and more informally is referred to as "assigning it to a variable").  So you should use something like `proc = subprocess.Popen(...)`

From there I recommend that you call `proc.poll()` to test if the program has completed, and either sleep (using the `time.sleep()` function, for example) or perform other work (using `select.select()` for example) and then checking again, later.  Or you can call `proc.wait()` so that you're sure the this ./pmm command has completed it's work before your program continues.  The `poll()` method on an subprocess instance will return "None" if the subprocess it still running; otherwise it'll return the exit value of the command that was running on that subprocess.  The `wait()` method for a subprocess will cause your program to block and then return the exit value.

After that you can call `(output, errormsgs) = proc.communicate()` to capture any output or error messages from your subprocess.  If the output is too large it could cause problems; using the process instance's `.stdout` (PIPE file descriptor) is tricky and, if you were going to attempt this then you should use features in the `fcntl` (file descriptor control) module to switch it into a non-blocking mode and be prepared to handle he exceptions raised when attempting `read()` calls on the buffer when it's empty.

Comment: ``proc.communicate()`` also waits for the child to terminate; so if you don't plan to do anything else meanwhile, you can call .communicate directly.